# Calculation of weighted average counts in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I am currently using to find counts
`select Name, Count(Distinct(ID)), Status, Team, Date from list`

In addition to the counts, I need to calculate a goal based on weighted average of counts per status and team, for each day.

For example, if Name 1 counts are divided into 50% Status1-Team1(X) and 50% Status2-Team2(Y) yesterday, then today's goal for Name1 needs to be (X+Y)/2.
The table would look like this, with the 'Goal' field needed as the output:

> [image: Blockquote]

What is the best way to do this in the same query?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as text tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Updated question to include details

Comment: The Goal field is essentially = (IDCount *Tracker)/sum(IDCount)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm almost guessing here since you did not provide more details but maybe you want to do this:

```
SELECT name,status,team,data,(select sum(data)/(select count(*) from list where name = q.name)) FROM (SELECT Name, Count(Distinct(ID)) as data, Status, Team, Date FROM list) as q
```